# getStrengthSupported returns true on Stock roms but false on custom roms

Tags: java, android, equalizer, custom-rom, lineageos

After i flashed my phone with LineageOS which is a custom rom, my equalizer got alot of `UnsupportedOperationExceptions`.

getStrengthSupported  also returns false on custom roms but true on stock android.

For now i just disable my equalizer if i catch this exception in a try-catch.

But i was wondering if there is another way so i can also support custom roms.

```
if (mBassBoost.getStrengthSupported()) {
        mBassBoost.setEnabled((short) progress > 0);
        mBassBoost.setStrength((short) progress);
        Log.i(TAG, "mBassBoost StrengthSupported: "+ mBassBoost.getStrengthSupported());
}else{
        Log.e(TAG, "mBassBoost StrengthSupported: "+ mBassBoost.getStrengthSupported());
}
        mBassBoostProgress = (int)progress;
        Log.i(TAG, "BassBoost Rounded Strength: " + mBassBoost.getRoundedStrength());
```

Comment: did you find it?? I am having trouble with `getStrengthSupported()' method.. it randomly returns true or false.

Comment: @aguagu also on stock rom?

Comment: I found it depends on which sound output device users use. if headset is connected, and the headset supports bassboost `getStrengthSupported()` returns `true`, but otherwise. so in my case, xiaomi A2's default speaker doesn't support setting bassboost strength. but when i connected headset and created (new BassBoost instance).getStrengthSupported() returned true.